# How would I get links from another file?

Tags: html, hyperlink

Instead of copying and pasting this same code into multiple pages I want to make a html file and then paste the code there and link all the pages to that one file to get the links. Is this possible??

Example of code

my code is

```
<a href="WebPage1.html"><img src="button1.png" onmouseover="this.src='buttonA.png'" onmouseout="this.src='button1.png'"></a>

<a href="WebPage2.html"><img src="button2.png" onmouseover="this.src='buttonB.png'" onmouseout="this.src='button2.png'"></a>

<a href="WebPage3.html"><img src="button3.png" onmouseover="this.src='buttonC.png'" onmouseout="this.src='button3.png'"></a>
```

What I'm trying to get

```
<link rel="WebNavigation.html"> ?
```

Something along those lines, I'm trying to use one line of code instead of 3

Comment: In HTML doesn't exists includes, it's an experimental functionality. You need to use a programming language like javascript or php

Comment: This is not possible with HTML. You can achieve this with PHP or a number of other templating engines using include statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?php include("your file location"); ?>` This should do the work using php.

e.g.

```html
<div class="web-nav">
  <?php include("WebNavigation.html"); ?>
</div>
```

You need some knowledge in php programming if you want to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Thanks; is there a method of doing this using JavaScript?

Comment: I believe that these is much more useful. Since files will be uploaded to the server, php is much needed because it is a `server-side` language. Javascript on the other hand `client-side`. Much more useful for page manipulation, animations, sending requests, etc.